# Get the template element in AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am using AngularJS and I want to create a button that does an action only if the user is registered. If the user is not registered, it opens a signup tooltip with a specific message. Here is the button markup:

```
<button signup-tooltip="submitForm()" signup-message="Please sign in to submit the form">submit form</button>
```

The signup tooltip template looks like this:

```
<div class="signup-tooltip-view">
    ....Many elements
    ....
</div>
```

Important thing is that the signup tooltip must opened above the button.
My signupTooltip looks like that:

```
module.directive('signupTooltip', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            action: '&signupTooltip',
            message: '@signupMessage'
        },
        templateUrl: 'path/to/signup/tooltip.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            function calculatePosition() {
                // This method calculates the position of the tooltip (above element)
                var top, left;
                ....
                ....
                ....
                return {
                    top: top,
                    left: left
                };
            }

            element.click(function() {
                if (user.isRegistered) {
                    scope.action();
                } else {
                    var tooltipPosition = calculatePosition();

                    // Here I need a reference for the template element <------PROBLEM
                    var tooltipTemplate = ..... HOW TO GET THE TOOLTIP ELEMENT

                    tooltipTemplate
                        .appendTo(element.parent())
                        .css(tooltipPosition);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Inside the directive I need a reference for the compiled element (the element that created from). How can I get it (keep in mind that I need signupMessage to be compiled with the template)??
What is the angular way for such use case (tooltips)?

Answer (score 1):

You should work more with the framework, not around it.

This is the "Angular Way" of doing things:

**JS:**

```
var template = '<button ng-click="onClick()">submit form</button>\
<div class="signup-tooltip-view" ng-bind="message" ng-show="!!position" style="top:{{ top }}px;left: {{ left }}px">';

module.directive('signupTooltip', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            action: '&',
            message: '@'
        },
        template: template,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            function calculatePosition() {
                // This method calculates the position of the tooltip
                var top, left;
                return {
                    top: top,
                    left: left
                };
            }

            scope.onClick = function() {
                if (user.isRegistered) {
                    scope.action();
                } else {
                    scope.position = calculatePosition();
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

*Of course you can put the template in a separate file and reference it with the templateUrl attribute instead of providing a string.*

**HTML:**

```
<signup-tooltip action="submitForm()" message="Please sign in to submit the form">
```

Here is the **[jsFiddle-demo](http://jsfiddle.net/23sy3c4c/4/)**

Comment: +1 This is exactly what I was talking about in the comments. Not sure how far out does OP want to move the tooltip though.

Comment: I have a list of more then 100 items. Each item has a button that opens the signup tooltip and does an action. I don't want to compile those 100+ directives where the user will press one or two buttons. The better solution will be something lazy. A directive that initiate all the compile only when the button pressed. What do you think?

Comment: If you want to use a directive for this task you have to compile the template anyway, so i would try this approach. And don't worry too much about performance, because creating 100+ directives is not as critical as you think. See this example with 250 elements: http://jsfiddle.net/23sy3c4c/5/

Answer (score 0):

Bearing in mind that `element` refers to your directive, this should do it (uses jQuery's find function):

```
var tooltipTemplate = element.find(".signup-tooltip-view");
```

If you're using only angular's jqLite, you'd have to go with the `children()` method because it doesn't support `find` for classes. Of course, you can always use plain JS to select it by iterating over its childNodes.

Comment: I don't want Angular to append the template to element. Is this the "Angular Way"?

Comment: Appending would be the angular way because directives should be used as standalone units. Why don't you simply make a higher-level directive that would render both the tooltip and the button markup (and simply use `replace: true`?

Comment: This way I'll have to find the template and then remove it from the element node (I need to append it to a different parent).
In addition, I don't like the idea of using the class name in the directive.
What do you mean by "higher-level directive that would render both the tooltip and the button markup"? (replace: true is deprecated)

Comment: Yeah, yeah, didn't understand you want the template outside of it. In such case, this is a bad approach. I'd still suggest you build a wrapper directive which would include the template parent and the button.

Comment: Currently this is a button, but I might use this directive for anchor or for other elements.
In addition, in a wrapper directive case I still have to remove the template from the element. Can you provide an example for such a wrapper directive?

Comment: Where should the template go then? You can't put it inside a common directive together with the button (or whatever element it becomes - this could also be specified in that common wrapper directive).

Comment: There will be an element definition that will contain all the tooltips.